# How to set a material that does not reflect light in Helix Toolkit ViewPort?

Tags: wpf, 3d, spotlight, helix-3d-toolkit

I create and render a list with 20 `SpotLight` points in `Helix` `ViewPort` that have specific positions. With a timer I always change the color of the `SpotLight`. The `ViewPort` light is set to:
 `<helix:DirectionalHeadLight Position="2,3,0" Brightness="0.30"></helix:DirectionalHeadLight>`

Than I also create a list and render a list of 20 spheres `SphereVisual3D`. The `SpotLight`s and `SphereVisual3D`s have similar positions. Than I set a material for the spehres (in this case indigo). See picture:

Figure 1: `SphereVisual3D` positions

[image]

Figure 2: `SpotLight` positions (with differentcolors per `SpotLight`)

[image]

I want to keep the spheres `Material` the same, without reflecting `light` from the `SpotLights`.
 I tried with all the 3 types of `Material`:

1: `sphere.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo));`

Figure 1.1: Spehres with `DiffuseMaterial` and `SpotLights`
[image]

2: `sphere.Material = new SpecularMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo),1);`

Figure 2.1: Spehres with `SpecularMaterial` and `SpotLights`
[image]

3: `sphere.Material = new EmissiveMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo));`

Figure 3.1: Spehres with `SpecularMaterial` and `SpotLights`
[image]

Is it possible to set a `Material` that does not reflect the light and keeps its color? Is there any possibility to set a plain color?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do this by means of the material only.

I suggest to replace the `SphereVisual3D`s by two-dimensional planes (circles) (e.g. using `MeshBuilder.AddEllipse()` in Helix) oriented towards the camera and use a `DiffuseMaterial`on them.

Of course, when the camera's position or look direction changes, you will have to react and change the orientation of the 2d elements accordingly.